# wordpress stdClass Object elements access

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to fetch the `term_taxonomy_id` from the array below but every time it gives me the following error.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in C.....

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 5
        [name] => fonts
        [slug] => fonts
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 2
        [object_id] => 96
        [cat_ID] => 5
        [category_count] => 2
        [category_description] => 
        [cat_name] => fonts
        [category_nicename] => fonts
        [category_parent] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: It would be great if you can show how you are trying to access this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried to get that error? Try this:

```
foreach($yourarray as $term){
  echo $term->term_taxonomy_id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. it was simple but dont know why i was confused.

Answer (score 1):

best and easy way

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try :

```
echo $array[0]->term_taxonomy_id;
```